# libGDX: Move an object up and down in a smooth way

Tags: object, animation, path, libgdx

I want to move an object up and down smoothly. It's for a gameover screen where the "continue"-button follow a smooth path up and down. 
I do not have any code to show, 'cause it's basically just about the principle.

Thanks for helpful answers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Scene2D` library and `Actions`, it will give you a lot of possibilities. Simple example:

```
Button continueButton = // ... initialize the button

float pathY = 100;
float duration = 3f;
continueButton.addAction(
        Actions.forever(
                Actions.sequence(
                        Actions.moveBy(0f, pathY, duration),
                        Actions.moveBy(0f, -pathY, duration)
                )
        )
);
```

For more info, read LibGDX wiki:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d,

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Actions,

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation